# How do I enable/disable flycheck when changing buffer content-type of web-mode

Tags: web-mode

I am using emacs daemon, and with the default config for js, jsx:

```
(flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)
```

When I edit *.html.erb files, I have an error: **Parsing error: Unexpected token** at `<%=` or `<%` on ruby code block.

I think `javascript-eslint` causes the problem. So, How do I select another flycheck checker or just disable automatically flycheck when I open *.html.erb files on web-mode?

Comment: Welcome to Emacs stackexchange :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the flycheck linter by doing this :- `M-x` RET `flycheck-select-checker` RET and chose the linter you need and press RET.

As for disabling flycheck for `web-mode` just for `*.html.erb` files, add this to your `.emacs` :-

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.html.erb\\'" . (lambda ()
                                    (web-mode)
                                    (flycheck-mode -1))))
```