# How to use web-mode engine-specific checkers in flycheck?

Tags: flycheck, web-mode

Flycheck seems to enable checkers based on the major mode.  Meanwhile, `web-mode` can be used to edit a variety of different types of files (html, javascript, etc.) which would each have their own distinct set of checker(s) that make sense to use.

For example, I've just enabled linting of my `jsx` files using the `javascript-eslint` checker, but now when I open an `html` file (in `web-mode`) flycheck tries to lint *that* using `javascript-eslint`, which fails miserably, of course, since the file is html, not javascript.

Is there any other way to tell flycheck which checker to use other than by the major mode?  Is there a way to tell flycheck to enable checkers for a given mode but only if some predicate passes, for example?

There's an answer to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/27832/573) that recommends completely disabling flycheck depending on the file type, but I don't want to do that since I'd like to lint my other `web-mode` files as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works, not sure if there's a "built-in" way of doing it...

```
(flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)

(defun my/configure-web-mode-flycheck-checkers ()
  ;; in order to have flycheck enabled in web-mode, add an entry to this
  ;; cond that matches the web-mode engine/content-type/etc and returns the
  ;; appropriate checker.
  (-when-let (checker (cond
                       ((string= web-mode-content-type "jsx")
                        'javascript-eslint)))
    (flycheck-mode)
    (flycheck-select-checker checker)))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'my/configure-web-mode-flycheck-checkers)
```

Comment: Strangly, if I do `M-x flycheck-select-checker javascript-eslint` in a web-mode file (say, .vue), a buffer similar to `M-x flycheck-verify-setup` opens showing, under `javascript-eslint`, that major-mode "web-mode is not supported", and an error saying `Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer`.